# Laravel sync Relation with optional parameters

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, relationship

I use the sync function for syncing a belongsToMany Relation:

```
$model->products()->sync($productIds);
```

In the $productIds array there is flat array with some Id's - 
something like this:

```
$productIds = [1,3,5,6];
```

What I want:
The pivot table has also additional columns like "created_by" and "updated_by".

But how can I add these fields to my array WITHOUT doing a foreach loop?
Is there a shorter way to do this?

I need an array like this:

```
$productIds = [1 => [
     'created_by' => 1,
     'updated_by' => 1
],3 => [
     'created_by' => 1,
     'updated_by' => 1
],5 => [
     'created_by' => 1,
     'updated_by' => 1
],6 => [
     'created_by' => 1,
     'updated_by' => 1
]];
```

Yes I know I can do it with foreach and add the columns while I loop through the array. But I want do it shorter.. is there a way to do it shorter (perhaps with laravel)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be enough to pass what you have set in **$productIds** in your code example to **sync()**.

This method works not only with array of integers. You can also pass an array where key is the synced ID and value is the array of pivot attributes that should be set for given ID.

This should do the trick:

```
$productIds = [
  1 => [
    'created_by' => 1,
    'updated_by' => 1
  ]
  //rest of array
];

$model->products()->sync($productIds);
```

Just make sure you have defined those fields as pivot fields in your relation definition.

In order to generate such table based on a list of IDs in $productIds you can do the following:

```
$productIds = array_fill_keys($productIds, array(
  'created_by' => 1,
  'updated_by' => 1,
));
```

Comment: I know how to sync a relation with more attributes.
What I want is to generate the array dynamically...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - you want to convert the array of IDs you have in $productIds into an array like above? Where IDs are keys and values are arrays where created_by/updated_by equals to 1?

Comment: no ... I dont want convert my array. I just wonder if there is the possibilty to extend my flat array ($productIds = [1,3,5,6];) into a multi dim array where the additional arrays are all the same like in my example above. So I have an array like $productIds , and another array like this: [
    'created_by' => 1,
    'updated_by' => 1
  ] and the second array has to be in place after each ID. And the question is: Is there a laravel way to get this, or is there anyway a solution WITHOUT a foreach of my $productIDs and attach the another array at each ID?

Comment: And updated it again, I've found an easier way using array_fill_keys