# Laravel syncWithoutDetaching extra field

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

How I can use Laravel [syncWithoutDetaching()](https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/Concerns/InteractsWithPivotTable.html#method_syncWithoutDetaching) method with setting extra field value?

For example I have custom table in my case:

```
product_id
customer_id
liked
pinned
```

And now I need to like product using `Customer` model but I see it's possible when I use `attach()` method:

```
$product = Product::find(1);
$product->reactions()->attach($product, ['liked' => true];
```

But when I run this command two times record will be duplicated in the table. Therefore, to avoid duplication I tried `syncWithoutDetaching()` but this method can't help to me, because this method accept only one parameter.

How I can solve this problem?

Comment: have you find the answer ?

Comment: Ans 1) https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/eloquent-sync-associate?page=1
Ans 2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34180963/laravel-sync-relation-with-optional-parameters

it may help you. it working for me